# Почему ругается компилятор? Регекс

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Компилирую регулярное выражение:

```
private static final String REGEX = "([\+\-]?[\,]?[\d]{1,3}[\,]?[\d]{1,3}[\,]?[\d]{1,3}[\.]?[\d]*)";
```

, а компилятор ругается "invalid escape sequence".
В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо за ответы.
Уже нашел ответ самостоятельно -- я не экранировал слэши.

Comment: А что Вы хотели написать? Кто такие `[\+\-]` ,  `[\,]` и пр.?

Comment: Хотел написать регулярное выражение, которое бы удовлетворяло следующим условиям:
 private static String[] validNumbers = { "+1", "1.0", "1,233",
   "1,233,456.34", "-1", ".34", "1,345,234,122,123" };

 private static String[] invalidNumbers = { "++1", "1.0.0", "1,23,3",
   "+-1233456.34", "002", "1.", "a1", "1,,2", "1 2", "1,2", ",2" };

Comment: Попробуйте

    import java.util.regex.*;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[+-]?\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})*(?:\\.\\d+)?|[+-]?\\.\\d+");
    for(int i=0; i<validNumbers.length; i++) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(validNumbers[i]);
    print(validNumbers[i]);
    print(m.matches());
    };
    private static String[] invalidNumbers = { "++1", "1.0.0", "1,23,3",
        "+-1233456.34", "002", "1.", "a1", "1,,2", "1 2", "1,2", ",2" };
    for(int i=0; i<invalidNumbers.length; i++) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(invalidNumbers[i]);
    print(invalidNumbers[i]);
    print(m.matches());
    };

Comment: Да, на print внимания не обращайте -- он из beanshell

Comment: Меня наставили на путь истинный на stackoverflow.com и я пришел к ответу:

"([\\+\\-]?[1-9]\\d{0,2})*(\\,\\d{3})*([.][\\d]+)?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java не PHP. Есть четко определенный набор символов, который может быть предварен символом обратный слэш. Ваше выражение должно быть записано так:

```
 private static final String REGEX = "([+-]?[,]?[\\d]{1,3}[,]?[\\d]{1,3}[,]?[\\d]{1,3}[.]?[\\d]*)";
```